# c# convert UTC to EDT

Tags: c#, datetime, utc

I know there are a lot of questions on this, BUT I am still confused!

How do I convert from UTC to EDT. i.e. To EST (New York in particular) but with Daylight savings?

I am trying this:

```
TimeZoneInfo edtZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
DateTime utcDT = UnixTimeStampToDateTime(double.Parse(fields[0]));
utcDT.Kind = DateTimeKind.Utc; //THIS LINE IS WRONG
DateTime edtDT = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcDT, edtZone);


//Put in for as requested
        public static DateTime UnixTimeStampToDateTime(double unixTimeStamp)
        {
            // Unix timestamp is seconds past epoch
            System.DateTime dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddSeconds(unixTimeStamp).ToLocalTime();
            return dtDateTime;
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: Please show the code for UnixTimeStampToDateTime.

Comment: For what it's worth, [DateTime.Kind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetime.kind.aspx) is readonly. If you *have* a local time and want to get the UTC of it, you can use [DateTime.ToUniversalTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime.aspx) but be careful with that. In any case, @JonSkeet showed a much cleaner way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect your `UnixTimeStampToDateTime` method is incorrect. Assuming it's taking the number of seconds since the Unix epoch, it *should* return a `DateTime` with a `Kind` of `Utc` already, e.g.

```
private static readonly DateTime UnixEpoch = 
    new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

public static DateTime UnixTimeStampToDateTime(double secondsSinceUnixEpoch)
{
    return UnixEpoch.AddSeconds(secondsSinceUnixEpoch);
}
```

EDIT: Now that we can see the existing implementation - yes, it's inappropriate. There's no reason why you should want to create an `Unspecified` value and then convert it to a `Local` one. Using the above should be fine, and more useful in general. Any existing calls which *need* a system local value should call `ToLocalTime` on the result of `UnixTimeStampToDateTime`.

(Alternatively, use my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) project, where you can use `Instant.FromSecondsSinceUnixEpoch` to get an `Instant`, and then do whatever you want...)

Comment: @ManInMoon: Yup, and it's basically flawed in the way I expected.

Comment: OK I see what you mean. I now changed mine to be .ToUniversalTime(). Am I now getting what I want. edtDT is always EDT?

Comment: @ManInMoon: No, you shouldn't use `ToUniversalTime`, because that's assuming the original value is in the *local* time. You should create it in UTC to start with - just as my example does. You don't want to perform *any* time zone conversions when creating the Unix time stamp - you just need to express that it's in UTC to start with. No other time zone needs to get involved.

Comment: OK. I think I understand(barely). My file data is definitely UNIX UTC. I am now using your code, and still doing this: DateTime edtDT = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcDT, edtZone); So now I seem to have EDT!

Comment: @ManInMoon: Yup, that sounds like it should be fine.